# Get application url with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, deployment, localhost

I need to redirect to the `CommonPage.aspx` page of my application when the session expires.

My application url would be similar to `http://Name_IP/applicationname/FolderName/Home.aspx`

From the above url I need to redirect to `http://Name_IP/applicationname/commonpage.aspx`

I have used below code to redirect

```
"http://localhost://" + Request.Url.Port.ToString() + "//applicationname/commonpage.aspx"
```

The above code will work in localhost. But it is not working after deployment.
How to do that? Please suggest

How to replace the localhost with Name_IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Request.Url`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains the complete URL from the request. Look at the `Host` property.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is by creating a new `Uri`:

```
var uri = new Uri(Request.Url, "applicationname/commonpage.aspx");
```

this will return a `Uri` who's value is

```
http://foo.bar:8080/applicationname/commonpage.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hostname, including port by using

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

which you can then use like

```
var url = String.Format(
    "{0}/{1}"
    Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority),
    "applicationname/commonpage.aspx")
```

which will produce something like

```
http://foo.bar:8080/applicationname/commonpage.aspx
```

Comment: Nice demonstration of `GetLeftPart`, but `String.Format` is complete overkill for a simple string concatenation.

Comment: @Richard You're absolutely right. I've added another answer which is a better way to do it anyway. I'll leave this one here for posterity though.